# Máscara para transformar número inteiro em string - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Bom dia!

Estou tentando implementar uma máscara em um número inteiro, cuja saída será uma string com caracteres embutidos.

Eu gostaria que o usuário entrasse somente com 12 dígitos inteiros e o banco copiasse esse valor automaticamente para uma string:

> Usuário entra: 123456789123
>
> Banco copia para o campo tipo character: "12-345.678/91-23"

Já consegui implementar uma trigger associada a uma função na seguinte tabela:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dmlu.teste_mascara3
(
    num numeric(12,0),
    num_proc character(16)
)
```

Trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER teste_trigger2
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON dmlu.teste_mascara3
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE dmlu.teste();
```

Função:

```sql
create or replace function dmlu.teste()
returns trigger as $teste$
begin
new.num_proc := to_char(new.num,'99"-"999"."999"/"99"-"99');
return new;
end;
$teste$
language 'plpgsql';
```

O banco até aceita essa sintaxe, mas, na hora de inserir um novo dado, ele simplesmente não me deixa salvar.
Se eu retiro as aspas, ele consegue copiar, com essa sintaxe:

```sql
new.num_proc := to_char(new.num,'999999999999');
```

Ou seja, o problema não é na função, e sim na máscara que estou tentando inserir.

Como posso inserir uma máscara de traços, pontos e barras num número inteiro em PostgreSQL?

Comment: tente "int_to_string", talvez funcione

Comment: Qual versão do PostgreSQL você está utilizando? Na versão 9.6 funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é no tamanho de seu campo `num_proc`.

```
SELECT char_length(to_char(123456789123,'99"-"999"."999"/"99"-"99'));
 char_length 
-------------
          17
(1 registro)
```

Aumente o tamanho de seu campo para `character(17)` e reteste. Ou utilize `text`.

Complementando: no psql apresentou o erro:

```
ERRO:  valor é muito longo para tipo character(16)
```

Da documentação: `If no explicit provision is made for a sign in to_char()'s pattern, one column will be reserved for the sign, and it will be anchored to (appear just left of) the number.` [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html]

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou!

Comment: Já estava me questionando porque tem 17 caracteres, mas entendi que é para o "sign".

Comment: Uma dúvida: não seria melhor você criar uma view com seu campo calculado e deixar seu banco de dados normalizado?